# Containers behind interface how can i spy content in debug

Tags: delphi, interface, spring4d

I'm using Spring4d where are interfaced containers like `IList<T>`. If I use normal version of container I can spy its content in debug by move mouse over variable. But if variable is interface I see somethink like this:
`TClassName($1234567) as IClassName`.
There is any way to spy it in debug?

I Have Delphi XE2.

Comment: In Delphi 2010 and later, a Delphi-style interfaced object (not a COM-style interfaced object) can be directly type-casted to its implementing class type, eg: `var Intf: IClassName; obj: TClassName; begin Intf := ...; obj := Intf as TClassName; // or obj := TClassName(Intf); end;` You should be able to do a similar typecast in the debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately the debugger does not understand generics pretty well, so when typing `TList<Integer>(list)` it complains about `E2029 '(' expected but '>' found`. However since most collection types inherit from `Spring.Collections.IEnumerable<T>` you can use `list.ToArray`.